# Can't navigate through the files

Tags: command-line, bash, files, directory, navigation

I have trouble in navigating through my files. Whenever I try to navigate or change the file directory I get this error:

```
No such file or directory
```

My current directory is `home/Atikin` and I don't have any files in it (after typing `ls` it gives no result and after typing `ls -l` it says `total 0`)

For example:

```
-bash: cd: /Downloads: No such files or directory
$ ls /Downloads/Icons
ls: cannot access '/Downloads/Icons': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu Server or Desktop?

Comment: Please leave this question closed. OP [commented](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815538/cant-navigate-through-the-files/815542#comment1235068_815542) that they're using Cygwin, not Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

You accidentally added a slash at the start of the path. Remove it and try again. I.e. use `Downloads/Icons` instead of `/Downloads/Icons`.

Comment: Most documentation I've seen suggests the tilde character, ie cd ~/Downloads or cd ~/Documents, etc. It's kind of a convention....

Comment: Yes, `~` is like `$HOME`. It's a shorthand for your home folder.

Comment: $HOME sounds like an environment variable.

Comment: Huh? `$HOME` **is** an environment variable.

Comment: Anyway you suggested he use Downloads/Icons and I suggested ~/Downloads/Icons would be more in line with industry standards. I fail to see how sticking an environment variable into a change directory command solves anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44335/discussion-between-wjandrea-and-wineunuuchs2unix).

Comment: but even though i dont have any other files ni my current directory :/ Everytime i type the command ls it doesnt give a response and if i type ls -l it says "total - 0" although im supposed to have files like downloads or documents

Comment: Run `cd` then run `ls -al`. Edit the output into your question.

Comment: total 28
    drwxr-xr-x+ 1 Atikin None    0 Aug 12 16:11 .
    drwxrwxrwt+ 1 Atikin None    0 Aug 12 15:49 ..
    -rw-------  1 Atikin None 1570 Aug 23 14:59 .bash_history
    -rwxr-xr-x  1 Atikin None 1494 Aug 12 15:48 .bash_profile
    -rwxr-xr-x  1 Atikin None 6054 Aug 12 15:48 .bashrc
    -rwxr-xr-x  1 Atikin None 1919 Aug 12 15:48 .inputrc
    -rwxr-xr-x  1 Atikin None 1236 Aug 12 15:48 .profile

Comment: idk if its helpful but i have a windows operating system and i downloaded it from cygwin website (https://www.cygwin.com/)

Comment: @Atikin This is an Ubuntu site. Why would you post here if you're not running Ubuntu?

Comment: does it really make a difference? I mean the terminal commands are still supposed to be the same...

Comment: Of course it makes a difference! Cygwin isn't supposed to have folders in the home directory! Excuse my frustration, but I spent some of my time answering your question, which was apparently wasted.

Comment: I'm really sorry for my lack of knowledge :(  would you still be able to explain to me how can i navigate through files using cygwin?

Comment: Ask the question over at SuperUser.com instead. I don't really have enough experience with CygWin to help.